# Transfer file from desktop application to web application

Tags: c#, .net, file-transfer

I have:

1. Web Application in Web Forms
2. Desktop Application in Win Forms

The aim is the desktop application is opened from the web application, which is already done using protocol handler. This desktop application should make some file or for the first try it could be just simple text and send it to the web application when I can receive it. What I should do to get it work? Which tool/framework or whatever do you prefer for such task ?

Comment: Let your desktop application issue an HTTP request to your WebForms app to upload the file?

Comment: You should do some research on the topic first. StackOverflow is a development community, that helps with specific technical questions.

Comment: Better term would be post and not transfer to your web app using http post method